# FTP permission denied error

Tags: windows, ftp, permissions

I am trying to FTP a RAR (zipped) file to another server but am having problems doing so.  This is a Windows environment.  I know that my FTP connection is setup correctly because I have already transferred over several other RARs.  But the difference from what I can tell is that this RAR that is failing is larger in size.  It is 761 MB.  So when I try to "put" it into the other server, I get the following:

```
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for WCU.rar.
> WCU.rar:Permission denied
226 Transfer complete.
```

However, the file is never transferred over.  Is there a size limitation?  And FYI, WCU.rar is a zipped directory, not a file.  But I was able to successfully FTP over several other zipped directories.

Comment: This is not 'programming related' (unless you were writing an ftp client or server) so this clearly belongs on www.superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be size limitation, not just stored data but as well transfered data. 
did you try to transfer a small file? a small file in the same format? I would say, permissions, but you said that you uploaded already files to this server.

just to help you debug, you can add both commands to your ftp session

ftp> hash
ftp> bin

Comment: Strange but after turning on the hash and waiting a couple hours it's working now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
WCU.rar:Permission denied
```

You don't have permission to write to that directory.  You need write permissions on the folder in order to do so.